# How to insert a translation into a subdocument nested in an array?

Tags: mongodb

With a schema like this, where the "items" field contains an array of subdocuments with nested translations :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("513740415b51ea0803000001"),
        "items" : [
                {
                        "id" : ObjectId("5137407f5b51ea100f000000"),
                        "title" : {
                                "en" : "Yes",
                                "fr" : "Oui",
                                "es" : "Si"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "id" : ObjectId("5137407f5b51ea100f000003"),
                        "title" : {
                                "en" : "No"
                        }
                }

        ],
}
```

How would you add a translation to a specific item id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$` positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#_S_) to update a specific array element of a doc.

For example, to add `"de": "nein"`:

```js
db.test.update(
    {'items.id': ObjectId("5137407f5b51ea100f000003")}, 
    {$set: {'items.$.title.de': 'nein'}})
```

The `$` in the `$set` object represents the index of the element in `items` that the query selection parameter matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

`db.yourColName.update({"items.id" : "itemId"}, {$set : {"translationField" : "translationValue"}})`

Over here in the first part of the query you are searching for the direct item in the array and set a new field + value for it.

The thing is, like you have already noticed, that Mongo doesn't have static schema. So `$set` will either update already existing field or create a new one. It all depends on the field name you set in the subquery.

To get to the direct document use the `$` operator: `items.$.title.fr` where `$` would represent the current object.

Comment: Thank you, but what should I put in "translationField" ? "title.fr" doesn't work. What command would you use to add the translation "fr" : "Non" to the item 5137407f5b51ea100f000003 ?